# Is there a way to get additional Morty Manipulator Chips before leaving the Citadel?

Tags: pocket-mortys

The game is relatively new, so I'm not sure if anyone will be able to answer yet,

Is there any way to obtain additional Morty Manipulator Chips (the in-game equivalent of a Pokeball) before leaving the Citadel of Ricks? As soon as I go through the portal, I encounter a random wild Morty, and have no way to capture it. I have already checked the one store in the Citadel I saw before heading out.

Comment: Is it possible there are no ways to get them? Since this is a pokemon clone, maybe its like how you need to walk into the tall grass for Prof Oak to yell at you before you have a chance to obtain chips?

Comment: Definitely possible. Wanted to make sure I wasn't missing one somewhere. Also, I wondered if someone had clicked on random objects around the Citadel and maybe found one, similar to how you could find random objects in Pokemon by clicking on trash cans or trees, etc.

Comment: I just want to jump in and confirm it is 3 badges. 2 badges then one council member. Immediately following the 3rd rick / 3rd badge. The chips went on sale only after that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will be able to get more after your first few trips through portals. You can also make them using recipes. I found this image of the recipes while making my own:  [image]

Answer (score 1):

In addition to crafting your own with the collected components, you can purchase Morty manipulator chips for 500 schmekles from Salesman Rick.  I do not believe they are immediately available, but they seemed to be available after I earned my first 2 badges and defeated my first Council Rick.

Comment: Not after beating 2 Ricks and one council Rick

Comment: @CanadianLuke Then maybe 3 Ricks? I've definitely been able to buy them, and I've only defeated 5 Ricks